# When was the Holy Grail first depicted as an object to be owned by its seeker?

Tags: history-of-literature, arthurian-legend

While the Holy Grail was always depicted as an important or powerful relic, in medieval literature I have never seen a quest to own the Grail, only to seek it in a spiritual sense. **In early stories, the seeking of the Grail was subordinate to a quest to fix a mistake.** This can be seen in *Perceval*, by Chretien de Troyes (c. 1190), and in its adaptation *Parzival*, by Wolfram von Eschenbach (c. 1210).

Later, the Grail became the actual object of the quest. This is seen in the Vulgate and Post-Vulgate versions of the Matter of Britain, most noticeably in Malory's *Le Mort D'Arthur* (1485). **In these later works, the objective of the quest was to be worthy of the Grail and to serve it** (for instance, taking it from Corbenic to Sarras), and **never to own it**.

**In most recent works, a search for the Grail often has its possession as objective**, due to its powers or significance. The earliest modern examples I know of are *War in Heaven*, by Charles Williams (1930), and Wagner's opera *Parsifal* (1882), in which Klingsor, having the Spear, also wants the Grail in order to destroy Amfortas. Even in *The Once and Future King* (1958), an Arthurian romance by T. H. White, it is initially implied that the objective of the quest is to bring the Grail to Arthur. As far as I know, this does not happen in the medieval romances. Examples in cinema are *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* (1989) and the loose adaptation of Arthurian romances *Excalibur* (1981).

My question is: when did literature start to depict the Holy Grail as an object to be owned? I do not restrict the question to works that present the Grail as the Holy Chalice.

Comment: I apologize for the poor phrasing of the title and parts of the question. Feel free to improve it!